# Ploting bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataframe of 1090 rows and 5 columns(A, B,C,D,E). All the values of each column variable range between 0 and 1. How can I plot a bar graph with x-xis showing intervals as 0-0.2, 0.2-0.4, 0.4-0.6, 0.6-0.8 and 0.8-1.0 for each of the column variables? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a solution which uses `melt()` for reshaping from wide to long format. Almost always, `ggplot()` works best with data in long format.

It also shows two variants for dealing with the column variables: stacking with different fill colours and faceting.

#### Stacked bar chart

```
library(data.table)
ggplot(melt(setDT(DT), measure.vars = names(DT))) +
  aes(x = cut(value, seq(0, 1, 0.2)), fill = variable) + 
  geom_bar() +
  xlab(("interval"))
```

[image]

This is similar to [dc37's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59744015/3817004) but calls `cut()` within `aes()`.

#### Faceted bar chart

```
library(data.table)
ggplot(melt(setDT(DT), measure.vars = names(DT))) +
  aes(x = cut(value, seq(0, 1, 0.2)), fill = variable) + 
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(vars(variable), nrow = 1L) +
  xlab(("interval")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

This might be more in line with OP's requirement of "a bar graph with x-axis showing intervals as 0-0.2, 0.2-0.4, 0.4-0.6, 0.6-0.8 and 0.8-1.0 *for each of the column variables*".

#### Data

This is a concise way to create a data.table with 5 columns of random numbers:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123L)
DT <- setnames(as.data.table(replicate(5L, runif(100L))), LETTERS[1:5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can 1) reshape your data into a longer format to have all your values in a single column and a categorical column containing A, B, ... 
2) Then, you can use the function `cut` to generate interval in your column containing values and count for each interval of each group:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Var", values_to = "Val") %>% 
  mutate(intervals = cut(Val, breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0))) %>% 
  group_by(Var, intervals) %>% count()

# A tibble: 25 x 3
# Groups:   Var, intervals [25]
   Var   intervals     n
   <chr> <fct>     <int>
 1 A     (0,0.2]      18
 2 A     (0.2,0.4]    19
 3 A     (0.4,0.6]    16
 4 A     (0.6,0.8]    24
 5 A     (0.8,1]      23
 6 B     (0,0.2]      17
 7 B     (0.2,0.4]    25
 8 B     (0.4,0.6]    18
 9 B     (0.6,0.8]    22
10 B     (0.8,1]      18
# … with 15 more rows
```

You can use the previous workflow and add it the plotting function like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Var", values_to = "Val") %>% 
  mutate(intervals = cut(Val, breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = intervals,fill = Var)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Does it look what you are expecting ?

**Data**

```r
df <- data.table(A = sample(1:100,100, replace = TRUE)/100,
                 B = sample(1:100,100, replace = TRUE)/100,
                 C = sample(1:100,100, replace = TRUE)/100,
                 D = sample(1:100,100, replace = TRUE)/100,
                 E = sample(1:100,100, replace = TRUE)/100)
```